# MYSQL join random row from another table for each row

Tags: mysql, join, random, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have two tables: Foods and Ingredients (refer to **Image 1** below).

**Image 1**
[image]

I wish to randomize the Ingredients to each Foods (can be duplicate ingredients for all Foods). How to use query to retrieve the price too? Thanks

I have tried using below SQL but not the result I wanted (refer to **Image 2**) because if using `sample SQL 1` the ingredients guaranteed same for all rows. If using `sample SQL 2` the price is also randomized not match with the respective ingredients.

```
/* sample SQL 1 */
select a.description, b.description, b.price
from Foods a
join (select a1.* from Ingredients a1 order by rand() limit 1) b
;

/* sample SQL 2 */
select a.description, (select a1.description from Ingredients a1 order by rand() limit 1) as description, (select a1.price from Ingredients a1 order by rand() limit 1) as price
from Foods a
```

**Image 2**
[image]

Comment: How can you tell the difference between description and description?

Comment: Sorry I knew what u meant, first one is the food description, 2nd is the ingredient description. I wish to randomized the ingredient for each row in Foods table, not just all foods same randomized ingredients. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use `row_number()` for this:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        f.description as food, 
        i.description as ingredient, 
        i.price,
        row_number() over(partition by f.id order by random()) rn
    foods f
    cross join ingredient i
) t
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works with older versions of MySQL database.

```
SELECT food, indeg, MAX(rn)
FROM (
       SELECT x.*, @rn := @rn + 1 AS rn
       FROM ( SELECT f.description AS food, i.description AS indeg
              FROM Foods f
              JOIN Ingredients i
              ORDER BY RAND()
             ) x
       JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0) r
    ) a
GROUP BY food
```